# SQL the elegant way of treating concurrency

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I havent found info on this subject yet, but maybe someone have tried doing this earlier. Imagine a heavily loaded web application (.NET/SQL Server 2008). The application serves clients that first request 'resources' and after a while 'submit' them. The resources are limited, so there is high risk of concurrent database access by several clients. The aim is to optimize the "request resource" mechanism in such way so that even when concurrent database access occurs the clients won't request overlapping database records and therefore the operation will be done as parallel as it is possible...

Conceptual database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Resources] (
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Data] [xml] NOT NULL,
    [Lock] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ResourceRequests] (
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ResourceID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [DateCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ResourceSubmits](
    [ResourceRequestID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [NewData] [xml] NOT NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

To request data, first I need to "reserve" it using "UPDATE" statement, this is the point of synchronization, because updates are executed sequentially

```
UPDATE T
SET T.Lock = (@lockID)
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP (@lockCount) R.*
    FROM [dbo].[Resources] AS R
    WHERE R.Lock IS NULL  
) AS T
```

(I'm not sure but...) As far as I know "UPDATE" operations use internal database locks and therefore it is not possible for two or more concurrent "UPDATE" operations will change the same record when using above query.

But when concurrent access occurs due to fixed order of "SELECT" only one of the clients will perform UPDATE at a time:

[image: Resulting data]

This is the result of concurrent execution, done by the following C#/Linq2Sql code:

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[20];

for (int threadIndex = 0; threadIndex < 20; threadIndex++)
{
    threads[threadIndex] = new Thread
    (
        new ThreadStart
        (
            delegate
            {
                using (var context = new L2S.l2sDataContext())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                    {
                        context.LockRoots(Guid.NewGuid(), 5);
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    );
}

foreach (var thread in threads)
{
    thread.Start();
}

foreach (var thread in threads)
{
    thread.Join();
}
```

As you can see the locks are distributed sequentially the order of Lock column values is not mixed, this means that the update operations were executed sequentially.

So the question, how to execute them on parallel and would it change something (except performance) if the "UPDATE" query will be changed the following way:

```
UPDATE T
SET T.Lock = (@lockID)
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP (@lockCount) R.*
    FROM [dbo].[Resources] AS R
    WHERE R.Lock IS NULL  
    ORDER BY NEWID() <--------------- The order is random now, but will the updates get executed concurrently?
) AS T
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "resources are limited"?  Limited, as in "a finite diminishing quantity-on-hand"?  Or limited as in "few in number but not diminishing in number".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to run your query as:

```
UPDATE top (@lockCount) T
SET Lock = @lockID
FROM
    [dbo].[Resources] T WITH (READPAST)
WHERE Lock IS NULL
```

Which will cause the UPDATE to skip rows which are already locked for update whilst searching for @lockCount rows for itself to update. Note that due to the nature of the way this works, the locks will still appear to be allocated in blocks of `@lockCount` at a time, unless, possibly, there are a *lot* of transactions in flight simultaneously. In fact, I'm struggling to think of a way to demo to your satisfaction that this is about as concurrent as you'll be able to get, but it is.

More on [READPAST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx)

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for! Thank you Damien_The_Unbeliever.

Comment: Using "WITH (READPAST)" I have increased performance in 2.6 times

Comment: Hmm strange first it was working fast, and then slower and slower, seems like database size is causing some problems

Comment: @Denis - indexes may or may not improve the situation - if it's having to perform a full table scan to find rows with a null Lock column, it will get slower as more rows are not null. But if the majority of rows are still null, an index may not be selective enough to improve matters. It's an odd setup, so not sure what to suggest to improve it further.